# Issue with local storage for to-do list

Tags: javascript, function, local-storage

I'm trying to add local storage to my to-do list. While refreshing the page does maintain the list item, the value comes back as undefined. I suspect it's something to do with the lack of an argument when I call the addInput function at the bottom, but I can't see a way around it.

In addition, if the toggled checked class is on and the item is crossed out, is there a way to store the class information?

I'd very much appreciate any help you can give me.

The offending code is below:

https://codepen.io/david-webb/pen/yLeqydK

```
function saveTodos () {
  let jsonstr = JSON.stringify(todos);
  localStorage.setItem('todos', jsonstr);
}

function getTodos () {
  localStorage.getItem('todoList')
  let jsonstr = localStorage.getItem("todos");
  todos = JSON.parse(jsonstr);
  if (!todos) {
  todos = [];
  }
}
 
//cross out text on click
     document.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
   if (ev.target.tagName === 'LI') {
   ev.target.classList.toggle('checked'); 
     saveTodos ();
    }   
   });

getTodos ();
addInput ();
```

Comment: Where have you stored todoList?

Comment: I think that's a mistake - thanks for pointing that out. I've changed it  to 'todos', but ut's still not working.

Comment: There's still some issue with the codepen you mentioned. Moreover, I think codepen won't allow you to access localstorage due to some security purpose.

Comment: This line was causing the pen to not work: let jsonstr = JSON.stringify(todo); You defined todo and used todos.

Comment: Okay - I suspected Codepen may be the issue. Although I've seen other pens in which local storage works.

Comment: Have you tried this code somewhere other than codeopen?

Comment: I tried this code by creating one HTML file it worked like a charm, nothings wrong with it.

Comment: Thakns for pointing that out. I've changed that line (and all others referring to 'todos', but it still isn't working.

Comment: Oh very sorry, didn't read your question entirely. The issue is that the items are not being retrieved on refresh, right sir?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: Give me a minute please, I'm looking into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this please:

```
<input type="text" style="font-size:25px;" id="input" placeholder="Write here">

<button id="addBtn">Add item</button>

<ul id="myUL">
</ul>

<script>
    let todo = [];

    document.getElementById('addBtn').addEventListener('click', function () {
        let value = document.getElementById('input').value;
        if (value) {
            todo.push(value);
            saveTodos()
            addInput(value);
        }
    });

    function addInput(text) {
        //add list item on click
        let listItem = document.createElement('li');
        let list = document.getElementById('myUL');
        let input = document.getElementById('input').value;
        let textNode = document.createTextNode(text);

        //create and append remove button  
        let removeBtn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
        list.appendChild(removeBtn);
        removeBtn.className = "removeBtn";
        removeBtn.innerHTML = "Remove item";
        listItem.appendChild(removeBtn);
        list.appendChild(listItem);
        listItem.appendChild(textNode);
        document.getElementById("input").value = "";
        removeBtn.addEventListener('click', removeItem);
        //console.log(todo); 
    }

    //remove list item on click  
    function removeItem() {
        let item = this.parentNode.parentNode;
        let parent = item.parentNode;
        let id = parent.id;
        let value = parent.innerText;


        todo.splice(todo.indexOf(value, 1));
        saveTodos();
        this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);
        console.log(todo)
    }

    function saveTodos() {
        let jsonstr = JSON.stringify(todo);
        localStorage.setItem('todos', jsonstr);
    }

    function getTodos() {
        localStorage.getItem('todos')
        let jsonstr = localStorage.getItem("todos");
        todos = JSON.parse(jsonstr);
        if (todos && !todos.length) {
            todos = [];
        }
        else{
            if(todos){
                for(var intCounter = 0; intCounter < todos.length; intCounter++){
                    addInput(todos[intCounter]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //cross out text on click
    document.addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
        if (ev.target.tagName === 'LI') {
            ev.target.classList.toggle('checked');
            saveTodos();
        }
    });

    getTodos();
    // addInput();
</script>
```

Call addInput within the getTodos function so that as soon as you're done with retreiving the list you print it.

[image: This is how its working]

This is what I changed:

1. function getTodos

   ```
     function getTodos() {
        localStorage.getItem('todos')
        let jsonstr = localStorage.getItem("todos");
        todos = JSON.parse(jsonstr);
        if (todos && !todos.length) {
            todos = [];
        }
        else{
            if(todos){
                for(var intCounter = 0; intCounter < todos.length; intCounter++){
                    addInput(todos[intCounter]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
   ```
2. Commented addInput().

Comment: Thanks a lot for looking into this for me. The changes have produced an error - in Codepen at least.

Comment: In the console, it says 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' ''. In the UI, the list item has been replaced by "//# sourceURL=pen.js"

Comment: I think you've copied some html tag in the js part as well. Have you copied <script> too? Moreover, can you please just create one html document and paste this code and try running, as I'm afraid the codepen won't work and will display you the same error that it was displaying me when I tried running your code pen.

Comment: I've copied it all into the <script> section of the HTML and it's coming up with this error: index.html:19 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at index.html:19. It produces the same error as an extrnal JS file

Comment: Which browser are you using? I can't replicate this issue in Chrome. :(

Comment: I'm using Chrome too

Comment: Added the screenshot.

Comment: Just do one thing, replace the getTodos function of mine with that of yours and don't call the function addInput() like you did before. See what happens.

Comment: That's working now - I think I just copied the code in wrong, sorry.One thing - is there a way to save the toggled class information? When you click on the list item, it crosses out the text, - but this isn't saved on refresh.

Comment: No problem. You might need to change the type of the information that you are currently saving. You are currently saving an array. An object with structure something like this might help you: [{text: 'Whatever the user writes', className: 'Any ClassName'}];.

Comment: This may not matter as I'm going to change the data structure as you recommend.. But out of curiosity, if you remove one item after the first refresh, the second refresh deletes all the items. The console tells me that the array data is also being deleted, so this may have something to do with it. Can you shed some light on this?

Comment: @DavidWebb, there is some issue with the addInput function of yours it seems.

Comment: Thanks @Helper. All sorted now!

Comment: Can you please consider accepting the answer if this was of any help?